# Popup is under a PDF iframe in internet explorer

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer, pdf, telerik, popup

I have PDF iframe on my main page and have to execute a popup with a form, but when i execute this popup appear under PDF iframe and i can't interact with it.

The PDF is generated with telerik and the popup is generated dynamically. The PDF is showing in the page with Adobe reader (if not doesn't work).

I try to made pdf transparent with wmode, change the value of z-index, and hide the pdf but in internet explorer 11 dont work (in others explorers works perfectly but i need in ie), the PDF is always above.

Someone knows how can I try to solve this trouble? Some new ideas?
Thanks in advance. :)

The telerik code is:

```
<telerik:RadSplitter ID="RadSplitter1" runat="server" Width="100%" Orientation="Horizontal" BorderSize="0">
                                    <telerik:RadPane ID="RadPaneFrame" runat="server" Height="700px" ShowContentDuringLoad="false" Scrolling="None">
                                    </telerik:RadPane>
                                    </telerik:RadSplitter>
```

My iframe is:

```
<iframe name="ctl00_RadPaneFrame" tabindex="-1" id="RAD_PANE_EXT_CONTENT_ctl00_RadPaneFrame" src="../../PDFWindow.aspx?rd=6963995" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" style="border: 0px currentColor; border-image: none; width: 915px; height: 700px; position: absolute;"></iframe>
```

And the popup is:

```html
<div class="modapopup" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_pnlMC" style="left: 622.5px; top: 171px; position: absolute; z-index: 10001;">
 
        <div class="container">
            <div class="header">
                <span class="msg" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_LabelTitleMC" style="font-size: 14px;">Registrar Medio Contacto</span>
                <a class="close" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lnkCancelarMC" onclick="$find('mediosContactoPopup').hide(); return false;" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$lnkCancelarMC','')"></a> 
            </div>
            <div class="body">
                <table>
                    <tbody><tr>
                        <td style="width: 50%; height: 30px; text-align: left;"> 
                            <span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_LabelMediosContacto" style="font-size: 12px; font-weight: bold;">Medio contacto</span> 
                        </td>
                        <td style="width: 50%; height: 30px; text-align: left;">
                            <select name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ddlMediosContacto" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlMediosContacto" style="width: 180px; text-align: right; font-size: 12px;">
  <option value="1">Presencial</option>
  <option value="2">Telefónico</option>
  <option value="3">Oficina Internet</option>
  <option value="4">Correo electrónico</option>

 </select>
                         </td>
                    </tr>
                     <tr>
                        <td style="width: 50%; height: 30px; text-align: left;"> 
                            <span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_LabelRegisterCode" style="font-size: 12px; font-weight: bold;">Registro llamada</span>
                        </td> 
                        <td style="width: 50%; height: 30px; text-align: left;" "=""> 
                            <input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$txtRegisterCode" tabindex="1" class="medium" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtRegisterCode" style="width: 170px; text-align: right; padding-right: 10px; font-size: 12px;" type="text"> 
                        </td>
                     </tr>
                     <tr>
                        <td style="width: 50%; height: 30px; text-align: left;"> 
                            <span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_LabelMailTitular" style="font-size: 12px; font-weight: bold;">Mail titular</span>
                        </td> 
                        <td style="width: 50%; height: 30px; text-align: left;">
                            <span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtMailTitular" style="text-align: right; font-size: 12px;">No hay Mail</span>
                        </td> 
                    </tr>
                </tbody></table>
                <br>
               <span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_notaFormMC">(*)</span> <br>
            </div>
            <div class="footer">
             <div id="BotonCorto">
                 <a class="BotonEstadoActivo" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_btnAceptarMC" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$btnAceptarMC','')">Guardar</a>  
                 <a class="BotonEstadoActivoCancelar" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_btnCancelarMC" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$btnCancelarMC','')">Continuar</a>
             </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    
</div>
```

Comment: When facing those kind of issue with IE and Telerik Css, my quick fix is to open F12. Select the Element to inspect every style rules apply to it. Compare them to the style apply in Firefox. Then add !important to the one I really want. 60% of the time it's enought.

Comment: @PierreLebon and the other 40%? The op is talking about iframes in IE. And I'm afraid of that and windowed controls of IE.

Comment: The other 40% are leverage to make my client quit WinXp.

Comment: @PierreLebon That was a big and nice deal. LoL

Comment: Eva, btw I failed to reproduce your issue with my simple pop up.

Comment: Don't worry @PierreLebon,  thank you for your attention.